Updating a cadastral feature hosted in Geoserver with an empty WFS through QGIS
I've looked through the similar questions and did not find what I'm looking for.
We have hosted a cadastral shapefile in Geoserver. We need to update this cadastral feature with new parcels, but we don't want anybody to modify the main feature online. We want the person in charge of creating new parcels to do it in QGIS through a WFS link (with empty content but having the same CRS and the same fields structure like the main feature) we'll send to him. After creating the new WFS parcel feature and saving it, it is dynamically uploaded and pasted to the hosted feature. It looks like giving a few part of modifying rights to a specific user, but denying the full modifying rights to him at the same time.
If it is possible, then how can we do that?
Background: I'm a GIS specialist with basic knowledge in PostGIS, GeoServer and OpenLayers. But I'm working with a developers team able to write complex scripts.

The user QGIS uses to talk to GeoServer will need write permission for the datastore, which should not be a shapefile but a database.

Thanks. Ok, "a database and not a shapefile". If we consider the database, that means that each new parcel created in QGIS will be a feature itself, not a part of the whole feature already hosted. Doing that, we'll get a database with too many individual features at the end. That's what we did not want to do.
